# apply method in companion class is not printing output to console

Tags: scala, singleton, companion-object

I created a class ApplyDemo with private construtor as

```
class ApplyDemo private{
    override def toString()="ApplyDemo"
}
```

I created companion object of the class as

```
object ApplyDemo
{
     def apply()={
            Console.println("calling Apply");
            new ApplyDemo
        }
}
```

Now I created a main app class as :

```
object MainApp extends App{

        val a=ApplyDemo;
        Console.println(a);
}
```

for curiosity pupose I put a println statement in apply method . but this is not called.
I am just curious to know why println is not called.

**P.S. both class and companion are in same file**

Thanks

Comment: By running `ApplyDemo()` (which calls the default `.apply()` method) you should see the `println` output.

Comment: Unless you' ve got more code you've not shown us, there's nothing there to call `apply`...

Comment: @bjfltecher: is there any difference in ApplyDemo() and simply ApplyDemo in this case ,because in scala docs i found that we can leave parenthesis

Comment: @Paul : I edited the code for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the answer in scala repl:
Expression :

```
val a= ApplyDemo
```

is assigning a type of ApplyDemo to variable a and scala repl says :

```
a: ApplyDemo.type = ApplyDemo$@xxxxxx
```

and expression

```
val a= ApplyDemo()
```

calls apply method in companion class and repl says.

**calling Apply

a1: ApplyDemo = ApplyDemo**

**Thanks to bjfletcher**